# How do I change the properties of an HTML as I'm duplicating it in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery to write a script that will completely dynamically duplicate the contents of an HTML div and then add a button to delete the corresponding "new div".  I am basically using this as a way to add more fields to a form.  I would've used an existing script, but all the ones out there seem to only add input fields and aren't very dynamic.  This way, I can use the button to duplicate exactly what I want by adding it to the HTML and NOT the JavaScript.

Everything seems to be working fine as far as duplicating the original container content is concerned.  The only thing I'm having trouble with is assigning an id to the remove button.  In my example, the parent div of the "original content" is "references"... so the first "new content" should have an id of 'references-1'... which it does.  When I create the remove button(based on the contents of the div shown below), I want to change it's id to 'references-1' so then when it's clicked, it will delete the "new content" div with the id of 'references-1'.  With my current script, none of the properties of the remove button are changed...

Anyone have any ideas?

The HTML

```
<div id="references">
    <!-- The content to duplicate.... excludes the parent div tag i.e. only the input tag. -->
    <input type="text" name="references[]" size="30" class="text-input" placeholder="Must contain a valid, working URL." style="position: relative;z-index: 0;">
</div>
<div id="more-references">
    <-- Where to put the new content -->
</div>
<div id="remove-button" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <-- The button that removes content --> <i class="fi-x"></i>

</div>  <i class="fi-plus" rel="addMore" id="references"></i>
<!-- The button that adds content -->
```

The jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    var i = 0;

    var oldRemove = $('#remove-button');

    $('[rel="addMore"]').on('click', function(){

        i++;

        var newRemove = oldRemove.clone();

        var buttonID = $(this).attr("id");
        var container = $('#' + buttonID + '-content');
        var content = container.html();
        var insertionPoint = $('#more-' + buttonID);

        insertionPoint.append('<div id="' + buttonID + '-' + i + '">' + content + '</div>');    

        newRemove.prop('id', 'remove-' + buttonID + '-' + i);               
        insertionPoint.append(newRemove.html());        

    });

});
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "When I create the remove button..., I want to change it's id to 'references-1' so then when it's clicked, it will delete the "new content" div with the id of 'references-1'". It almost sounds like your meaning to set the same id to two html elements, which is a no-no.

Comment: Everytime the user clicks the add more button, a new div will be created with the new content in it... that div will have id "references-1" for the first, "references-2" for the second, "references-3" for the third, etc.  So the "remove button" for that div will have an id of the corresponding number... maybe I will make it a class.

Comment: Or you could add that as a [data attribute](http://api.jquery.com/data/). So the new div will have id="reference-#", and your remove button can have data-reference="reference-#". Then onclick, you can get which div the button is referring to by simply calling `$(this).data( "reference" )` and then do what you will with it.

Comment: Ok that sounds like a good idea... but back to my original question, how would I change the data of the new remove button?

Comment: I would recommend setting the data attr of the new button with the id of the new div dynamically. I put this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxqkt/1/) together to illustrate this.

Comment: @filoxo your implementation indeed works. There's just one challenge. Because of how you're binding the remove buttons some buttons have multiple binds. [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/jxqkt/2/) should illustrate. Copy, say 4 times, then remove, watching the console output. That can be avoided by using a delegated bind as in my answer below.

Comment: @user3558931 AWESOME! I put my demo together quickly and knew it wouldn't be up to par, which is why I posted it as a comment instead. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few corrections and one modification here and there and we're good to go. First I changed remove button id to class. Then I store the id of the div each button would remove in a data attribute.

Second, the i element had the same id as the div to duplicate leading to invalid html,

Third, there's no element #references-content, only #references exists.

A simple delegated bind binds all the remove buttons:

```
$(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var oldRemove = $('div.remove-button'),
        div = $('<div/>');
    $(document).on('click', 'div.remove-button', function() {
        $( $(this).data('del') ).remove();
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $('[rel="addMore"]').on('click', function(){
        i++;
        var buttonID = $(this).data("id");
        var newRemove = oldRemove.clone().data('del','#' + buttonID + '-' + i).show();
        var container = $('#' + buttonID );
        var content = container.html();
        var insertionPoint = $('#more-' + buttonID);
        insertionPoint.append( div.clone().attr( 'id', buttonID + '-' + i ).html( content ) );
        insertionPoint.append( newRemove );        
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/hFMvT/3/show/)

**EDIT**

The code above has been edited to use the existing remove button that I missed earlier. However, I changed the id to a class and continue to store in each button the id it's meant to remove in a data attribute data-del.

Here is the only change I made to the HTML: `id` --> `class` and `visibility: hidden` --> `display:none`.

```
<div class="remove-button" style="display:none;">
    <-- The button that removes content --> <i class="fi-x"></i>
</div>
```

To modify the code so that the new buttons are added inside the new divs - I think it's something you might consider - make the following modifications:

```
insertionPoint.append( div.clone().attr( 'id', buttonID + '-' + i ).html( content ) );
insertionPoint.append( newRemove );
```

To:

```
insertionPoint.append( div.clone().attr( 'id', buttonID + '-' + i ).html( content ).append( newRemove ) );
```

And remove

```
$(this).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are not creating a new remove button, but appending the existing one to the new `references` element.

If you want to clone, then change the data in it without changing the original one, use [jQuery.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
var remove = $('#remove-button').clone();
remove.prop("rel", "removeThis");
remove.prop("id", buttonID + '-' + i);
var removeButton = remove.html();

var newHtml = '<div id="' + buttonID + '-' + i + '">' + content + '</div>';
insertionPoint.append(newHtml);
insertionPoint.append(removeButton);
```

If this does not solve your problem, please clarify.

Comment: This idea makes sense, however, when I add .clone to the remove variable, it shows up as [object Object].  I updated the jQuery in my original question.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 That's because you're concatenating html with the jQuery object. So it is being converted to the string `[object Object]`. Change the call to two appends, one for the html string, another for the jQuery object. Alternatively, you could call `removeButton.html()` to get the html string from the cloned remove button, but this is less efficient.

Comment: Another thing, the cloned remove button should be created inside the `.on` event, otherwise it would reuse the same clone in all add contents. It should be a new one every time.

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix the clone object, but no properties are being applied to the remove button.  I updated my code again.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 I believe I have a solution for your as posted in the my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML put the button in source with a known and unique id (in this case SOURCEID:

```
<div id="references">
    <!-- The content to duplicate.... excludes the parent div tag i.e. only the input tag. -->
    <input type="text" name="references[]" size="30" class="text-input" placeholder="Must contain a valid, working URL." style="position: relative;z-index: 0;">
</div>
<div id="more-references">
    <-- Where to put the new content -->
</div>
<div id="remove-button" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <div id="SOURCEID_btn">BUTTON</div> <i class="fi-x"></i>

</div>  <i class="fi-plus" rel="addMore" id="references"></i>
<!-- The button that adds content -->
```

Then in JavaScript :

```
var newRemove = document.createElement('DIV');
newRemove.id='remove_'+i+'_cnt';
newRemove.innerHTML=oldRemove.innerHTML.replace('SOURCEID', 'remove_'+i);
oldRemove.parentElement.appendChild(newRemove);
```

Then to get button:

```
function getRemoveHandler(i)
{
return function() {
var o=$('#remove_'+i+'_cnt');
alert('Remove: '+i+': '+o.id); };
}

vat btn=$('#remove_'+i+'_btn');
btn.bind('click', getRemoveHandler(i));
```

So new items will have its own id, new buttons will have its own id, and all the content will be duplicated, when click the button you will have source object... Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are sufficient but you should encapsulate the entire thing.

E.g.

```
 function MyLogicForWhenAddIsPressed(x,y,z){

 //Check if element has a URL with regex inter alia

//Make a request to url

 //Upon Success register call to (MyLogicForWorkingUrl)
  //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A direct reference data property or id with counter is not necessary. You can use this code that work with the manner of jquery event.

Feel free if you have questions to following code:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <button class="js-copy">Copy</button>
    <div id="reference">
        <input type="text" name="references[]" size="30" class="text-input original" placeholder="Must contain a valid, working URL." />
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    function generatedHTML() {
        return $('<div />', {'class': 'reference'})
            .append(
                $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'placeholder': this.placeholder}),
                $('<button/>', {'class': 'js-remove','text': 'remove'})
            );
    }
    function dublicateInput(event) {
        var container = $(event.delegateTarget);
        var input = container.find('input.original').get(0);

        container
            .append(generatedHTML.bind(input));
    }
    function removeInput(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget)
            .off('click')
            .closest('div.reference')
            .detach();
    }

    $('#container').on('click', 'button.js-copy', dublicateInput);
    $('#container').on('click', 'button.js-remove', removeInput);
});
```

You can [play with code at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxqkt/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Place a basic html to clone it. Put the remove button inside the remove button inside the text input you want to duplicate. Then the remove button only needs to remove its parent (the wraping div). No ids necesary. (Example using addresses)

```
<style>
#basicAdress, #manyAddress .addressContainer:first-child .remove{
    display: none;    
}
</style>
<!-- html base  -->
<div id="basicAdress">
<div class="addressContainer">
    <p><label>Address</label><input type="text" class="txtAddress"/> <input type="button" class="remove " value="Remove" /></p>    
</div>
</div>

<div id="manyAddress">
    <!--here goes copies-->
</div>
<div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#basicAdress .addressContainer:eq(0)').clone().appendTo('#manyAddress');


    jQuery('#manyAddress').on('click','.remove',function(){
        //remove cloned element
        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
    });

    jQuery('#addMore').click(function(){
        //make copies
        jQuery('#basicAdress .addressContainer:eq(0)').clone().appendTo('#manyAddress');
    });

    jQuery('#sendAddress').click(function(){
        jQuery('#outputAddress').html('');
        jQuery('#manyAddress .addressContainer').each(function(i, v){
            jQuery('#outputAddress').append(
                "<p>" + (i+1) + '. ' + jQuery(this).children().find('.txtAddress').val()+ "</p>"
            );
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/gcjxy/3/)